# How to Add a filter to single.php only in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I want to add nofollow rel to tag cloud on single post only. This function code in functions.php works fine but I couldn't figure it out how to restrict it to single.php only.

```
function szub_nofollow_tag($text) {
return str_replace('<a href=', '<a rel="nofollow" href=',  $text);
}


add_filter('wp_tag_cloud', 'szub_nofollow_tag');
```

Could you please tell me how to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular

Should do the trick, remember to use it inside the function itself as I don't think WordPress knows if it's true/false while parsing functions.php

```
function szub_nofollow_tag($text) {
    if ( is_singular() )
        return str_replace('<a href=', '<a rel="nofollow" href=',  $text);
    else
        return $text;
}


add_filter('wp_tag_cloud', 'szub_nofollow_tag');
```

Comment: I have tried it already and re-tried it now. The single post shows the tag cloud with nofollow attribute but on all other pages (including front page and archives pages), tag cloud is hidden/not showing.

Comment: @AamirUsman: But you have asked about single.php in specific, so what you comment looks like that you asked exactly for that. Please make yourself more comfortable with the Wordpress Page hierarchy: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Well, friend, it hides the whole cloud (whole widget). Whereas I want to add nofollow on single.php and remove the nofollow on other pages. I want to keep the widget on all pages. I hope you understand now.

Comment: Try adding in else return $text; in that case.